# Find words containing straight apostrophe (as opposed to curly apostrophe)

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have inherited a text with words containing apostrophes, some of which are "curly" `’`, and some straight `'`. In order to process the text I need a reliable search method which will produce only exact matches for my search text.

So far, whenever I search the text for a word containing a straight apostrophe (like `he's`), Word also returns a match for the same word containing a curly apostrophe (`he’s`) and I do not want this to happen. I want exact matches with `'` straight apostrophes only.

The VBA instruction I'm using is:

```
MyRange.Find.Execute FindText:=strSearchText, Forward:=True, Format:=False, _
    MatchCase:=True, MatchWholeWord:=True
```

Can anybody give me a hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From VBA's <kbd>F1</kbd> help for the `Find.Execute` method:

> To search for a symbol character, type a caret (^), a zero (0), and then the symbol's character code. For example, "^0151" corresponds to an em dash (—).

For a straight apostrophe this would be `^039`. So for example, if you're searching for `he's`, then you will want

```
FindText:="he^039s"
```

This does not find the curly apostrophe equivalent, `he’s`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew the VBA-Help, but I thought this was just a method to enter characters into a search string which can't be found on the keyboard. I didn't realize, that for some characters it isn't possible to enter them any other way. It changes the length of the search string, which doesn't really come in handy, but it makes the search unambiguous.